# AngularJs : List Polling

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular with the `$interval` service to grab data from backend periodically using `$ngResource`.

Each time I'm getting my new list from the backend, I'm replacing the old one by the new one. I then display the list in a template using `ng-repeat`.

The issue with this approach : each time the data update, my interface blinks. Plus, if I was selected a text in this list, my selection disappears with each list refresh.

Is there an easy way to keep my frontend and backend list synced appart of a forloop on the new data and pushing them in the old one ?

Comment: You probably do something incorrect, your solution is the standard way and should perfectly work. Please show an [MCV exemple](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Try using `track by` in the `ng-repeat`. That will tell the `ng-repeat` not to destroy rows present in both the old _and_ new list: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: Check out `angular.extend` as well, as it can be of some use in updating an existing object without breaking references held by the view.